# show view in modal windows

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Hi everyone I am doing a website in joomla 3

I want to execute a task when I open a modal windows, I show the view in the modal  for this I do this..

this is the router of task to execute

```
<?php $link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_projects&view=proyectos&task=este&id='. $item->id);?>



<div class="span4">
<a href="#.<?php echo $link; ?>" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">
<img src="<?php echo JURI::root()?>/<?php echo $item->imagenportada; ?>"/></a>
</div>
```

and now the modal windows

```
    <div id="<?php echo $link ?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body…</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

but don´t work. any idea!

Comment: some clarification would help... like what's actually going wrong.. what have you tried...

Comment: Have you read through this? http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_modal_form_field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out that Twitter Bootstrap's JS and CSS is loaded
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Answer (score 0):

Finally I add to my link

```
 <a href="#modal"  title="<?php $item->id?>" id="<?php echo $item->id; ?>" role="button" class="picture" data-toggle="modal">
```

and the modal windows

```
    <div id="modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body…</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
```